# Chrome extension client side showing successful but server generating 500 error

Tags: javascript, http, flask, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I've been stuck on this for half a day, as I am not sure why on one console it's successful but on another is not.

I am trying to make a POST call from chrome extension/client-side to flask server.

background.js

```
fetch('http://0.0.0.0:5000/test',
    {
        method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({"name":"daniel"}),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }       
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)));
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "To be named",
    "description": "This extension helps...",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "identity.email",
        "http://0.0.0.0:5000/test"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },  
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/"], 
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "css": ["styles.css"]
    }]
}
```

PY (flask)

```
@blueprint.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return request.json#{"status": "OK", "status_code": 200, "data": data}
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return request.json
    else:
        return 'nothing printed'
```

Solutions tried so far:

- request.loads/dumpts(request.json)

  Installing CORS on flask

  changing Content-Type to Content-'t'ype

^All these solution just returned `null` as a response instead of error and didn't get the actual data as presented in the background console

Background js console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHOGI.png)

test dev:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYgNH.png)

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

and on console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

[null screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzq1I.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for your `test` route:

```py
@blueprint.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response_dict = {
            "status": "OK",
            "status_code": 200,
            "data": data 
        }
        return jsonify(response_dict) # Import jsonify: from flask import jsonify
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return jsonify(request.json)
    else:
        return 'nothing printed'
```

`request.json` simply calls `request.get_json()` with default arguments and it tries to parse the request data to JSON, it does not return a `Response` and that is why it is invalid response.

If you want to return some JSON to your client, `jsonify` is a handy function for that.

Docs: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I still get `null` from that code too

Comment: What appears to be `null`? Please share a screenshot or something.

Comment: Here is working example: https://gist.github.com/vremes/208c21a7f83a84011902e702bf634d8a

Comment: thanks for getting back & for the example, I have pasted the screesnshot's link at the end of the post. As well as, I have tried your example to on the chrome extension but no success either :(

Comment: Result: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`